# Rails join a list of strings with commas and "and" before the last

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a standard rails helper that converts an array of strings like `["apple", "banana", "pear"]` into `"apple, banana, and pear"` for inserting into a sentence?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Yeah to_sentence ought to work nicely.

http://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence

Comment: Just when I thought I couldn't be more impressed with Rails, I run into this beauty...