# Join an array of strings with a different final delimiter

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

Generally: How do I join an array of stings such that the last delimiter is different than the others?

Specifically: How does the iOS Messages app construct the default name of a group conversation, which is a list of contacts' names?

Example

```
class User {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

let users = [
    User(name: "Matthew"),
    User(name: "Mark"),
    User(name: "Luke"),
    User(name: "John")
]

users.list(" & ") { $0.name } // => "Matthew, Mark, Luke & John"
```

PHP

- [Implode array with ", " and add "and " before last item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586141/implode-array-with-and-add-and-before-last-item)
- [Replace the last comma with an & sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687665/replace-the-last-comma-with-an-sign)
- [How to edit the implode so it will join values with two strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613847/how-to-edit-the-implode-so-it-will-join-values-with-two-strings)

Ruby (on Rails)

- [Rails join a list of strings with commas and "and" before the last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300242/rails-join-a-list-of-strings-with-commas-and-and-before-the-last)

Python

- [How to join list in Python but make the last separator different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083949/how-to-join-list-in-python-but-make-the-last-separator-different)

C# (Linq)

- [Comma separated list with "and" in place of the last comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123396/comma-separated-list-with-and-in-place-of-the-last-comma)

Answer (score 5):

Using the class defined in the question you could do something like this:

```
let names = users.map { $0.name }
let suffix = names.suffix(2)
let joined = (names.dropLast(suffix.count) + [suffix.joinWithSeparator(" & ")]).joinWithSeparator(", ")

print(joined)   // prints Matthew, Mark, Luke & John
```