# Adding the word "and" before the final item of an array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

I have a list of items in an array. The default output of the items is a simple list separated by commas. However, a proper sentence would include the word *"and"* between the second last and last item in the list.

---

**Swift code:**

```
    let myItem1: String = "Apple"
    let myItem2: String = "Bee"
    let myItem3: String = "Carrot"
    let myItem4: String = "Dog"

    let myArray = Set(arrayLiteral: myItem1, myItem2, myItem3, myItem4)

    //print("Item count:", myArray.count)
    print("Item list:", myArray.joinWithSeparator(", "))
```

---

**Output:**

The current output above is: "Apple, Dog, Carrot, Bee"

However, the proper output should be: "Apple, Dog, Carrot ***and*** Bee"

---

**Question:**

> How can I modify the code so that the output includes the word *"and"*
>   between the second last and last item in the list?

Comment: Remove the last item, join with `, ` as you do now. Add _and_ & last item.

Comment: Related: [Join an array of strings with a different final delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39496725/join-an-array-of-strings-with-a-different-final-delimiter)

Comment: Unrelated: Why is your set of strings named `myArray`? Also you should never have to use the `init(xyzLiteral:)` initialisers directly, they're meant for the compiler to use. In this case you can just do `let mySet : Set = [myItem1, myItem2, myItem3, myItem4]`

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Hamish. I guess `myArray` is better explained as `mySet`. `arrayLiteral` was used because Xcode suggested it and was retuning an error prior to that.

Answer (score 5):

Pop the last element and then add it onto the string later:

```
let last = myArray.popLast()

let str =  myArray.joinWithSeparator(", ") + " and " + last!
```

Editing:

```
    let myItem1: String = "Apple"
    let myItem2: String = "Bee"
    let myItem3: String = "Carrot"
    let myItem4: String = "Dog"

    let mySetArray = Set(arrayLiteral: myItem1, myItem2, myItem3, myItem4)

    var myArray = Array(mySetArray)

    let last = myArray.popLast()

    let str =  myArray.joinWithSeparator(", ") + " and " + last!
    print(str)
```

Comment: Wow, same thought!

Comment: We might be both wrong though, because this way we get `,`s around the `and`.

Comment: we're well caught.

Comment: Provided a fix! :)

Comment: Excellant solution!

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. In Swift 2.2, Xcode 7.3, getting the error "Ambiguous reference to member 'popLast()'". Any ideas why this might be occurring?

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz- OP is using set instead of array.

Comment: That's correct, a Set is used to remove any duplicates in the array before giving the final list. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can now just do

`ListFormatter.localizedString(byJoining: names)`

This gives

`Apple, Bee, Carrot and Dog`

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
    let myItem1: String = "Apple"
    let myItem2: String = "Bee"
    let myItem3: String = "Carrot"
    let myItem4: String = "Dog"

    let myArray = Set(arrayLiteral: myItem1, myItem2, myItem3, myItem4)

    //print("Item count:", myArray.count)
    print("Item list:", myArray.joinWithSeparator(", "))

    var joinedString : NSString =  myArray.joinWithSeparator(", ")

    let lastRangeOfComma = joinedString.rangeOfString(",", options: .BackwardsSearch)
    joinedString = joinedString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(lastRangeOfComma, withString: " and")
    print("\(joinedString)")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Given an array of `String(s)`

```
let words = ["Apple", "Bee", "Carrot", "Dog"]
```

you can simply write

```
let sentence = words.dropLast().joinWithSeparator(", ") + " and " + words.last!

// Apple, Bee, Carrot and Dog
```

> This code needs the `words` array to contain at least 2 elements to work properly.

Comment: Quite sophisticated aprrocuh!

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrNames:[String] = ["Apple","Bee","Carrot","Dog"];
var allNames:String!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    allNames = arrNames[0]

    for i in 1...arrNames.count-1{
        if i == arrNames.count - 1 {
            allNames = allNames + " and " + arrNames[i]
        }else{
            allNames = allNames + ", " + arrNames[i]
        }
    }

    print(allNames)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible ways is to use functional programming:

```
let myArray = ["Apple", "Bee", "Carrot", "Dog"]


let mapedArray = myArray.dropLast().map{
    myArray.indexOf($0) == myArray.count - 2 ? $0 + " and " + myArray[myArray.count - 1] : $0 + ","
}
```